# How to terminate a navigation controller and embed different views in a different navigation controller?-Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, navigationcontroller

I have an app with several views for a user to create an account. All these view are embedded within a `UINavigationController`. Once a user creates an account, they will be directed to the app's home screen. At this point, I no longer want the original `UINavigationController` to influence the rest off the application and instead have the actual working of the app embedded in a new `UIViewController`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your app's home screen the initial view controller (or the `UINavigationController` it is embedded in if you are using navigation). When your app loads you can check to see if the user is logged in or needs to create an account. If they need to login/create an account, create a new `UINavigationController` make your login/create account view controller the new `UINavigationController`'s `rootViewController`. Present the new `UINavigationController` modally and the user can create an account. When they have created an account, you can call `self.dismissViewController(...)` from your home screen (via notification or whatever method you prefer) and the login/create account views will be dismissed; leaving the user back at your home screen.